# Entity Framework 6.1 : The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have a table with some relations, the program works fine until I add a new relation between this table and `customer` table, the ddl for `PermissionCode` Table (first table) is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PermissionCode] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[Salt] varchar(3) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[Code] nvarchar(12) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[StartDate] date NULL ,
[EndDate] date NULL ,
[TypeId] int NOT NULL ,
[UserId] nvarchar(128) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[OwnerId] int NULL ,
[CategoryId] int NULL ,
[IsActive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)) ,
[InsertIdentifier] varchar(8) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[IsForTeacher] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)) ,
CONSTRAINT [PK__Table__3214EC0759063A47] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_PermissionCode_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT [FK_PermissionCode_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([OwnerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT [FK_PermissionCode_PremissionCodeType] FOREIGN KEY ([TypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT [FK_PermissionCode_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT [UQ__Permissi__DB7779646E01572D] UNIQUE ([Salt] ASC, [Code] ASC)
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO   

CREATE INDEX [IX_PermissionCode_Code ] ON [dbo].[PermissionCode]
([Code] ASC) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and the ddl for my `customer` table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[UserId] nvarchar(128) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[OfficeName] nvarchar(200) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[CityId] int NULL ,
[StateId] int NULL ,
[Address] nvarchar(1000) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[Tel1] nvarchar(20) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[Tel2] nvarchar(20) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[Fax] nvarchar(20) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[ResponsiblePersonFirstName] nvarchar(50) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[ResponsiblePersonLastName] nvarchar(100) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NULL ,
[Deleted] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)) ,
[CustomerType] varchar(10) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT [PK__Customer__3214EC07345EC57D] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Customers_City] FOREIGN KEY ([CityId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[City] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Customers_State] FOREIGN KEY ([StateId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[State] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Customers_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I use [Entityframework.bulkinsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) plugin to bulk insert permission codes for a customer. If I remove `FK_PermissionCode_Customer` foreign key the program runs without error, and insert permission codes successfully to db, but when adding this fk relationship entity framework issue this error:

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>      at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.BindForeignKeys() in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:line 603
>      at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappings.DbMapping..ctor(DbContext context) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappings\DbMapping.cs:line 101
>      at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.EfMap.Get(DbContext context) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\EfMap.cs:line 60
>      at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Extensions.MappingApiExtensions.Db(DbContext ctx, Type type) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Extensions\MappingApiExtensions.cs:line 51
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
>      at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Helpers.MappedDataReader`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 enumerable, IEfBulkInsertProvider provider) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Helpers\MappedDataReader.cs:line 58
>      at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.Run[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, SqlTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.cs:line 22
>      at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase`2.Run[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, IDbTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:line 77
>      at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase`2.Run[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, BulkInsertOptions options) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:line 105
>      at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext context, IEnumerable`1 entities, SqlBulkCopyOptions sqlBulkCopyOptions, Nullable`1 batchSize) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:line 95
>      at EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext context, IEnumerable`1 entities, Nullable`1 batchSize) in c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:line 75
>      at xxx.Domain.Repositories.PermissionCodeRepository.InsertRange(IList`1 permissionCodes) in xxx.Domain\Repositories\PermissionCodeRepository.cs:line 92
>      at xxx.Admin.Controllers.PermissionCodeController.Create(CreatePermissionCodeViewModel model) in xxx.WebUI.Admin\Controllers\PermissionCodeController.cs:line 169

I can't found the problem; for testing purpose, I change my db first to code first approach and problem solved. but I want to now the reason for this issue, is this a bug? or am I need do one more step in entity framework model designer?

Comment: @Gert Arnold: the error is given in title, there was no more than this string: "The Given key was not present in the dictionary."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. It happened because you have rename your pocos and/or dbsetnames.

Retry dbfirst without rename and you'll certainly bulk it!

Comment: Could you explain more? what you mean from renaiming pocos, I completly delete edmx file, and recreate it but still not work

Comment: Bulk uses EntityFramework.MappingAPI to map pocos. It uses the SSPace method to retrieve table names in your metadataworkspace (http://blog.cincura.net/230583-metadataworkspace-in-entity-framework/). The problem is that MappingApi doesn't found the table in the metadataworkspace but doesn't launch any error.So it breaks in bindingforeignkeys beacause it doesn't have any foreign keys => it doesn't have the table. If this is not your problem, try debugging the dll ;)

Comment: I haven't renamed anything - what would be the cause of this issue? It works doing it normally (but slow!).

Comment: I am running DB First and I haven't renamed anything. But I still cannot get to run BulkInsert. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225183/entity-framework-bulk-insert-throws-keynotfoundexception-the-given-key-was-not Would appreciate any help because `AddRange` is extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in the following situation:

- DB first
- no *manually* renamed entities after updating the model from the database.
- a table called **Users**
- '*Pluralize or singularize generated object names*' enabled

I resolved it by renaming the table to **User**.

NB: I dug a little with .Net Reflector to get to a solution and I assume that the EntityFramework.MappingAPI is trying to find the table **User**, because the the POCO is called **User**, although didn't dig further once I had it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was caused by the Column attribute used on a random entity. E.g.:

[Column("LanguageName")]

public string Name { get; set; }

It is clearly a bug in the BulkInsert columns mapping.

As a side note: the developer that didn't check the key in that dictionary should feel bad. He has wasted a lot of time for us.

Happy codding.